# Finding possible numbers to yield a certain arithmetic mean (average)

Tags: arithmetic, average

I'd like to know how I could find the possible numbers to yield a certain average number (arithmetic mean), given that:

- the arithmetic mean will be calculated from 20 integer numbers, each having a possible value between 18 and 30
- 7 of said numbers are known and their sum is 180
- the arithmetic mean should be comprised between 28 and 30

Thank you

Comment: Are the numbers integers or any real numbers?

Comment: If you know how many numbers there are, it's _much_ easier to work with the total _sum_ of the numbers, rather than the average.

Comment: They're integers and the sum of the 7 known ones is 180.